# Python 3 function to loop over pandas data frame to change schema

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm converting a bunch of pandas data frames into spark df then writing to hdfs. Also explicitly specifying the schema to change all data types into string to avoid the merge class conflict.

Trying to write a function that will loop through all the pandas df columns, create the schema then I can use the schema to convert to spark.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def creating_schema(df):
    for columnName in df.columns:
        schema = StructType([(StructField('"' + columnName + '"' , StringType(), True))])
        print(schema)

    return(schema)
```

This outputs:

```
StructType(List(StructField("column_1",StringType,true)))
StructType(List(StructField("column_2",StringType,true)))
StructType(List(StructField("column_3",StringType,true)))
StructType(List(StructField("column_4",StringType,true)))
StructType(List(StructField("column_5",StringType,true)))
```

However, I believe I need something in this format for it to work:

```
schema = StructType([StructField("column_1" , StringType(), True),
                    StructField("column_2" , StringType(), True),
                    StructField("column_3" , StringType(), True),
                    StructField("column_4" , StringType(), True),
                    StructField("column_5" , StringType(), True)
                    ])
```

Any help in writing this function would be helpful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def creating_schema(df):
    sf = []
    for columnName in df.columns:
        sf.append(StructField(columnName, StringType(), True))
    return StructType(sf)
```

Proof:

```
pdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=["column_1","column_2","column_3","column_4","column_5"])
schema=creating_schema(pdf)
sdf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)
sdf.printSchema()
root
 |-- column_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column_2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column_3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column_4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column_5: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: You may think about changing `StructField('"' + columnName + '"' , StringType(), True)` to `StructField(columnName, StringType(), True)`. I think quoting a string is not necessary.